# Why is the div hiding but not showing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a program that, when a button is pressed, a function is called and everything is hidden except one div. But I don't understand why this isn't working. If there is some simple fix, I would be grateful, but I may be going about this problem completely wrong.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1");
  var y = document.getElementById("main");
  y.style.display = "none";
  x.style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
#div1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Show only Div 1</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to do this without jQuery, but if that is the only way possible to achieve what I am trying to do, then I will use that.

Edit: Suppose I have lots of divs. Is there any quick way to hide all of them but one, without jQuery, without having to individually go through all the divs and hide them?

Comment: An element inside a `display: none` element cannot be made visible.

Comment: Your code doesn’t hide div2 at all.

Comment: Come on,... the parent is "none". What do you expect?

Comment: This is a prime example on why you should use descriptive variable names

Comment: Only way to hide a parent and show it's children is using `visibility` instead of `display`

Comment: Why can't I just change `y.style.display = "none"` and `x.style.display = "block"` to `y.style.visibility = "hidden"` and `x.style.visibility = "visible"`? It would achieve what I want to achieve, but it still works in more or less the same way.

Comment: @WilliamJones With `visibility` the `main` won't collapse to its contents height, as you can see in this fiddle, where I positioned the button outside it so you can see how it behaves: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7v2ybm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use a class instead, and `addEventListener`, as inline script is not recommended and neither are altering styles inline.

On `button` click, add a class to the `main` and then use its CSS rule to hide the chosen `div`, e.g. using the `nth-child(n+2)` or `:not(:first-child)`

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle('hideallbutdiv1');
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#main.hideallbutdiv1 div:nth-child(n+2) {  /*  or div:not(:first-child) */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <button>Show only Div 1</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is spiced version using a pseudo element to toggle the text on the button

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle('hideallbutdiv1');
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
}

button::before {
  content: attr(data-show)
}

#main.hideallbutdiv1 div:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}

#main.hideallbutdiv1 button::before {
  content: attr(data-hide)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <button data-show="Show only Div 1" data-hide="Show all"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to hide the container. Simply hide the div you are targetting:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1");
  var y = document.getElementById("div2"); //  change it to div2 NOT main
  y.style.display = "none";
  x.style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide all the children of `main` except the `div1`, you have to hide all the siblings of `div1` directly.

The function to get siblings would look like this:

```
function getSiblings(elem) {
        var siblings = [];
        var sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
        var skipMe = elem;
        for ( ; sibling; sibling = sibling.nextSibling ) 
           if ( sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling != skipMe )
              siblings.push( sibling );
        return siblings;
    }
```

Your button click handler:

```
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("div1");
      var siblings = getSiblings(x);
      siblings.forEach(function(y){
        y.style.display = "none";
      });
    }
```

[Here's the working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/w02sutpj/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide the container, or it will hide all its children.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1");
  var y = document.getElementById("div2");
  y.style.display = "none";
  x.style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
#div1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Show only Div 1</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: hide your button too using the same method, if you really want **only** div1.

Answer (score 0):

you are hiding `main` which contains all 3 divs.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1"); // <- you dont need this cause its visible initially
  var y = document.getElementById("div2");
  var z = document.getElementById("div3");
  
  x.style.display = "block"; // <- you dont need this cause its 
  y.style.display = "none";
  z.style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#div1 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Show only Div 1</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```